# show a funct. is differentiable (m.variable)

Tags: real-analysis

I have a general function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and I know that $|g(x)|/|x|^{1/2}$ is bounded but I want to know how to show that it is differ. at x. All i know is the basic definition of differentiable (the linear transformation one)

Comment: Do you think $g(x)= |x|$ is differentiable at the origin?

Comment: @zhw. no I do not

Comment: Well then we're done with the problem aren't we?

Comment: @zhw. I don't believe we are..

Comment: Well $|x|/|x|$ is bounded but $|x|$ is not diff at the origin, so there's a counterexample.

Comment: @zhw. Apologies, I mistyped: $|g(x)|/|x|^{3/2}$ is bounded.

Comment: if $n=1$ can you answer it?

Comment: @zhw. Yes I can

Comment: OK, so you know $g'(0)=0$ in that case. What do you think $Dg(0)$ will be in higher dimensions? by the way, you should write $|g(x)| \le C|x|$ for all $x,$ otherwise we don't know what's happening at the origin.

Comment: @zhw. so would showing $\dfrac{|f(h) - f(0)|}{|h|} \to 0$ as $|h| \to 0$ be sufficient then?

Answer (score 1):

You have that $|g(x)|/|x|^{3/2} \leq M$ for some constant $M$.

First notice that $|g(x)| \leq M|x|^{3/2}$ so that $|g(0)| \leq 0$ so $g(0)=0$.
Also, we have $|g(x)|/|x| \leq M|x|^{1/2}$.

If the following limit is 0, then $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|g(x)-[g(0)+0 {\bf\cdot} x]|}{|x|}$.

But $g(0)=0$, $x {\bf\cdot} 0 =0$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|g(x)|}{|x|} \leq \lim\limits_{x \to 0} M|x|^{1/2} = 0$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|g(x)-[g(0)+0 {\bf\cdot} x]|}{|x|} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|g(x)|}{|x|} = 0$ (i.e. $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$).